# Send a notification to my iPhone when a website's content changes

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, notifications, monitoring

I would like to be notified quickly (ideally within an hour) if a certain website (that is not under my control) changes. Any changes to the HTML should trigger a notification.

Since I am not always monitoring my email but I have my iPhone on me most of the day, I am probably looking to receive a push notification or SMS message once that happens.

Any recommendations for an app or service that can help me with that? I am willing to pay for it.

Comment: If the site is not 100% static html then there is huge chance that you get different html every request.

Comment: You make a good point @wwk - network timeouts and other polling and post processing s needed. No one that’s gotten pager duty would want notification on a single bit changing on one scan IMO. Hopefully the services recommended are more adept than the simplest possible solution proposed here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I did not consider that. However it looks to me like this specific government site that I'm looking to monitor seems to produce exactly the same HTML for every request in the few hours that I've been checking it manually. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Urlooker](https://urlooker.com/tracks) offers paid plans that monitor for changes up to as frequently as every 30 minutes and has email notification built in. You can monitor the whole page or selected elements only.

Urlooker offers integration with [Zapier](https://zapier.com/explore) and [ifttt](https://ifttt.com/services) if you prefer actions offered by those platforms to be triggered.

Comment: This looks like a good service. I will wait for a few more hours, perhaps someone can suggest a solution that does not require 2 different services to be used to get the push notification. :)

Comment: @LouisB. maybe just the urlooker email service sent to your iCloud address would work for you ;) good luck!